# Error after used pub upgrade and the error show RC2Parameters that never heard

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

After I used `pub upgrade` I got this error and I don't know why. Although I comment on the `crypto` package(I see the `crypto` is a path in the error) this error still appears.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/basic_utils-5.5.1/lib/src/library/crypto/rc2_engine.dart:4:1: Error: 'RC2Parameters' is imported from both 'package:basic_utils/src/library/crypto/rc2_parameters.dart' and 'package:pointycastle/api.dart'.
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile the application.
```

I tried to ctrl+shift+f to find `package:basic_utils/src/library/crypto/rc2_parameters.dart` and `RC2Parameters` but this is not found.

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2728], locale th-TH)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: There's currently a problem with `basic_utils` - see the static analysis at https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils/score Either use an earlier version or contact the developer.

Comment: But I don't use this package or this is basic package in the flutter?

Comment: This happens when I import the mongo_dart package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `basic_utils` is the cause of this issue.

This error happened when importing any package that has a dependency on `basic_utils`, either direct or transitive as mentioned in [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/122892#issuecomment-1474818768).

For me, this package that uses the `basic_utils` is the `mongo_dart`.

The solution that can fix this issue before the maintainer of the `basic_utils` package fixes this is to override the dependency by adding the following lines in the `pubspec.yaml` as mentioned in [github](https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/issues/327#issuecomment-1474898692):

```
dependency_overrides:
  basic_utils: 5.4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the package

```
dependency_overrides:
  basic_utils: "5.3.0"
```